# angularjs + php + mysql (live search) works slow

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I have one but HUGE problem with that stack of technology. It works well for me, but in my database I have more than 50K records, and it works not as fast as I thought before. When I'm trying to insert some letters to my input it looks like my PC doesn't have enough memory )))

I think the problem could be in my PHP code. May be I should do some optimization of my code???

**PHP code**

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("XXXX", "XXX", "XX", "XXX");

$connect->set_charset("utf8");

$result = mysqli_query($connect, 
    "SELECT addresses.fullname AS addressname, addresses.latitude, addresses.longitude, areas.fullname AS areaname, 
    areas.image_url AS areaimage, areas.site, gek.name AS gekName, gek.phone AS gekPhone, gek.email AS gekEmail, 
    gek.description AS gekDescription, gek.addressInformation AS gekAddressInformation
        FROM addresses
        LEFT JOIN areas ON addresses.areaId = areas.id
        left JOIN gek ON addresses.gekId = gek.id");

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

    echo json_encode($data);

    mysql_close($connect);
```

**my JS CODE**

```
app.controller('InfoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.searchFilter = '';
        $scope.search = function() {};
            $http.get('data/addresses.php')
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.addresses = data;
                })
                .error(function() {
                    $scope.data = "Error";
                });
        }
    ]);
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchFilter" placeholder="введите свой адрес"
                    typeahead="address as address.addressname for address in addresses | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
                    ng-focus="showMarker(searchFilter)"
                    typeahead-min-length='1'
                    typeahead-on-select='onSelectPart($item, $model, $label)'
                    class="form-control" />
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on your database tables? Have you run an EXPLAIN for the query to see how MySQL is executing it?

Comment: I actually don't know what you mean **"What indexes do you have "**. Could you enplane and write any step to check it? 
Do not run "EXPLAIN". I don't know what is it ) But will try

Comment: Database tables can have indexes that help make access to the data more efficient - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html should explain what indexes are and do, and how to use them

Comment: thx a lot. I'll read about it. 
And hope will find out )

Comment: I've made some investigation according to my query and what did I find.
If I use only one table in my query it works more faster  than in case when I use query with other tables. 
Here are screens for my structure and explain result
[link] (http://tinypic.com/r/314xg2e/8) - structure
[link] (http://tinypic.com/r/8xre5x/8) - explain 
Any help ?